# How to disable a TextField by clicking a button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can a button disable a TextField, so when I click the button I can't change the TextField's value?

Answer (score 0):

Both `TextField` and `TextFormField` has a property called `enabled`, it's a bool, also you need to add a controller, and this can be achieved controlled by :

```dart
bool? enabled;

TextFormField(
  enabled:enabled
)

//for the button
GestureDetector(onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    enabled = false;
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `TextField` enabled property to false when the button is pressed. Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool isTextFieldEnabled = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(children: [
        TextField(enabled: isTextFieldEnabled,),
        ElevatedButton(child: Text('Press Me To Disable TextField'), 
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isTextFieldEnabled = false;
          });
        },),
      ],)
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use enabled false on text field:

```
TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    enabled: false,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Current Miles',
   ),
),
```

but if you still want to handle a click on your text field you should use follow:

```
  TextField(
  readOnly: true,
  enableInteractiveSelection: true,
  onTap: () {
    do_something(),
  },
),
```

you need to use 'setState' on you button 'onPressed' and put any of the above needed flags in a variable and set accordingly.